# Extra space using display grid

Tags: html, css

I add some styles to my page.

```css
.container {
     display: grid;
      grid-gap: 15px;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 300px);
  background:red;
  height:100vh
}
.item {
  border:5px solid;
  height:150px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
</div>
```

I want to have the whole background colored in red.
Why i have some extra white space at the buttom of the `.container`? How to delete it?

Answer (score 0):

use min-height instead of height

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 300px);
  background: red;
  min-height: 100vh
}

.item {
  border: 5px solid;
  height: 150px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the background to red on the whole page, you can apply the red color background to the body instead of using red background for the container.If you want something else, please let me know.

```css
.container {
     display: grid;
      grid-gap: 15px;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 300px);
      
}
.item {
  border:5px solid;
  height:15px;
}
body{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
</div>
```

The second method is that you can use height of the container as **height: -webkit-fill-available;**

```css
.container {
     display: grid;
      grid-gap: 15px;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 300px);
      height: -webkit-fill-available;
      background:red;
}
.item {
  border:5px solid;
  height:15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
  <li class="item">test</li>
</div>
```

Please run this one in full screen.